# Find the occurrence of a word in a list: my code is returning 0 and I'm not too sure why?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count, sequence

I'm not exactly sure what's going on here. The result is 0. I'm trying to find the occurrence of a word in a list.

```
def count(sequence,item):
    total=0 #counter

    if type(sequence)==list or dict: #the if works for a list or list of lists
        for element in sequence:
            if element ==item:
                total+=1         
    else: #the else works for strings, where item is a word             
        sequence=sequence.replace(',','') #remove commas
        sequence=sequence.replace('.','') #remove periods
        sequence=sequence.lower() #make lowercase
        
        for word in sequence.split():  #will iterate through words instead of characters
            if word==item:
                total+=1
    return total
    

print (count(["Hello how are you today.","today you are"], "you"))
```

Comment: `if type(sequence)==list or dict` is always true

Comment: What is the expected behaviour for `dict` objects?

Comment: try ```if type(sequence) in [list, dict]:```

Comment: You probably meant to say ```if type(sequence) == item or type(sequence) == dict```.   Note, though, that the logic won't work if you have more deepley nested lists.

Comment: To expand @BTables' comment above.  This is a common beginner's mistake.  What you wanted to write is `if type(sequence) == list or type(sequence) == dict`.  The `or` connects two booleans.

Comment: if you must check the type, you better use isinstance it even accepts multiple things. type() == ... is not so good. so `isinstance(sequence, (list, dict))`. also, dict is not a sequence so name is not so good too

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, `if type(sequence)==list or dict` will always evaluate to true since `dict` is truthy. I think what you're looking for here is `if type(sequence) == list or type(sequence) == dict`

All that being said you can just use the built in function `count` like so:

```
x = ["Hello how are you today.","today you are"]
search_word = 'you'
total = 0
for i in x:
    total += i.split().count(search_word)
print(f'Got tota: {total}')
```

Comment: Thank you. You simplified my code. Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The two issues were mentioned already as comments. The condition to your first if statement is wrong. Also, you are checking if each string in the list or dictionary of strings is entirely equal to the search word, which does not seem to be what you want to achieve based on the provided example. Instead, both cases should aim to check if the word is in a sentence, with the first case (`sequence` is a `list` or `dict`) checking this for each iterable item in the sequence.

As such, we factor out the check into its own function, and call this function as need to increment the counter.

```
def isWordInSentence(searchWord, sentence):
    sentence=sentence.replace(',','') #remove commas
    sentence=sentence.replace('.','') #remove periods
    sentence=sentence.lower() #make lowercase

    for word in sentence.split():  #will iterate through words instead of characters
        if word==searchWord:
            return True
    return False

def count(sequence,item):
    total=0 #counter

    if type(sequence)==list or type(sequence)==dict: #the if works for a list or list of lists
        for element in sequence:
            if isWordInSentence(element, item):
                total+=1         
    else: #the else works for strings, where item is a word             
        if (isWordInSentence(sequence, item):
            total+=1
    return total
```

```
print (count(["Hello how are you today.","today you are"], "you"))
```

Output:

`2`

Answer (score 0):

This returns 0 because 0 is the correct answer!

```
["Hello how are you today.","today you are"]
```

is a list, and none of the items in the list are equal to "you".